# Ubuntu system Does not see ram

Tags: ram

I am running ubuntu 14.04 and just installed 2GB of ram in addition to the 4GB I already have. However when I look under about computer it show me only having 2.7 . when I run "sudo lshw -class memory" it clearly shows that I have 2x 2GB sticks and 2x 1GB sticks. What is going on?

```
  *-firmware              
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.0.5
       date: 09/14/2007
       size: 128KiB
       capacity: 1984KiB
       capabilities: isa pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot zipboot biosbootspecification netboot
  *-cache
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: a
       slot: Internal Cache
       size: 32KiB
       capacity: 32KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 24
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 6GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
          product: M3 78T2863RZS-CF7
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 0
          serial: 64869EF2
          slot: DIMM1
          size: 1GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
          product: NT2GT64U8HD0BY-3C
          vendor: Nanya Technology
          physical id: 1
          serial: B74E3E3B
          slot: DIMM2
          size: 2GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
     *-bank:2
          description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
          product: M3 78T2863RZS-CF7
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 2
          serial: 64869EF8
          slot: DIMM3
          size: 1GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: DIMM DDR2 Synchronous 667 MHz (1.5 ns)
          product: NT2GT64U8HD0BY-3C
          vendor: Nanya Technology
          physical id: 3
          serial: 874E3E3B
          slot: DIMM4
          size: 2GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 667MHz (1.5ns)
```

Edit:

Here is my kern.log. I will add the other stuff when I get home.

```
Dec 31 19:00:53 mag-downstairs-linux kernel: [    0.000000] e820: BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
Dec 31 19:00:53 mag-downstairs-linux kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009ebff] usable
Dec 31 19:00:53 mag-downstairs-linux kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000009ec00-0x000000000009ffff] reserved
Dec 31 19:00:53 mag-downstairs-linux kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000f0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
Dec 31 19:00:53 mag-downstairs-linux kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x00000000afe8ffff] usable
Dec 31 19:00:53 mag-downstairs-linux kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000afe90000-0x00000000afee2fff] ACPI NVS
Dec 31 19:00:53 mag-downstairs-linux kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000afee3000-0x00000000afeeffff] ACPI data
Dec 31 19:00:53 mag-downstairs-linux kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000afef0000-0x00000000afefffff] reserved
Dec 31 19:00:53 mag-downstairs-linux kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000e0000000-0x00000000efffffff] reserved
Dec 31 19:00:53 mag-downstairs-linux kernel: [    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fec00000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
```

Comment: If you go to bios, what does it show regarding RAM size?

Comment: Might it be that your SODIMMS might be laid out as 2x1GiB and 2x2GiB (rank 2 memory, or effectively two memory setups per DIMM). As for the 2.7... As Pilot already write: Check the BIOS first. If that sees the full 6GiB then check if you are running a normal 64 bit setup and not some 32bit-without-PEA.

Comment: Look through your `dmesg` or /var/log/kern.log for the bios e820 section and add that.

Comment: Are you sure that your video card isn't getting memory from the RAM?

Comment: I have a dedicated video card with 4GiB of ram so it should not be getting any memory from my ram

Comment: The bios sees 6Gibs of ram

Comment: I am running a full 64bit Version of ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0):

You may need to switch the cards. Right now you have the 1GB cards on bank0 and bank2, with the 2GB cards on bank1 and bank3.

**Check with your manufacturer**. According to

http://h20331.www2.hp.com/Hpsub/downloads/Mini_WP_Z800_memory.pdf

and

https://superuser.com/a/107753/317065

You may need to put the two 2GB cards on bank0 and bank2 instead.

---

Alternatively, according to [here](https://superuser.com/a/384413/317065) there may be a BIOS setting under chipset configuration > internal graphics for frame buffer location. In that post, the user changed the setting from above 4GB to below 4GB and problem was solved.